# Calculate Teradata Query Execution Time

Tags: sql, performance, teradata, execution-time

I'm trying to compute Teradata queries execution time for a specific Teradata user. I currently have the following query inspired from there:
[Calculating-the-actual-query-run-time](https://community.teradata.com/t5/Database/Calculating-the-actual-query-run-time/td-p/43894)

### Query:

```
SELECT date
,a.username
,a.errorcode
,SUBSTR(b.sqltextinfo, 1, 15000)
,a.starttime
,a.firstresptime
,a.firststeptime
,((a.firstresptime - a.starttime) HOUR(4) TO SECOND(2)) AS elapsedtime
,((a.firstresptime - a.firststeptime) HOUR(4) TO SECOND(2)) AS executiontime
,elapsedtime - executiontime AS delaytime
FROM dbc.QryLogV a
INNER JOIN dbc.QryLogSqlV b ON a.procid = b.procid AND a.queryid = b.queryid 
WHERE a.Username = 'xxx';
```

Sadly it's triggering the error:

> Executed as Single statement.  Failed [7453 : HY000] Interval field overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Years ago the datataype for the timestamps in DBQL changed from `TIMESTAMP(2)` to `TIMESTAMP(6)`, now when you try to get `SECOND(2)` in your result it overflows. To fix this either use `SECOND(6)` or ``SECOND`.

Btw, depending on your release, you'll find `ElapsedTime` & `DelayTime` pre-calculated in dbc.QryLogV.